# Routing requests to external services(Webhooks) using Istio

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, envoyproxy

I have micro-services based infrastructure. And I need to redirect all the requests of each service to external service(`Webhook`) without changing code and without affecting the original routes.

Is `Istio` the best way to do that? Is it possible to redirect requests to specific `webhook` by only configuring `Istio` (without additional code in services).
Is it possible to redirect request to multiple destinations?

Thanks.

Comment: can you at least change the authority? (please take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier to understand what I mean)

Comment: Please take a look for  [Egress Gateways](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic)